# The degree of crime

Tags: vocabulary

X does a bad thing, so does Y. The bad thing is categorized as an offense/sin. X's offense is bigger than Y's offense. How would we describe the degree using the word 'criminal'?

X is a bigger criminal.

X is a grave criminal.

X is a serious criminal.

I don't think if we can use 'grave' as an adjective before a person to describe the seriousness and higher degree of his offense.

Comment: I would probably use "Worse" as my first choice

Comment: _X is a greater criminal than Y_ or _X is the greater criminal of the two_. If you are comparing two things you need the comparative form of the adjective.

Comment: X is criminallier than Y

Comment: @PeterKapteyn If you're going to joke, make it clear. Someone will actually believe you.

Answer (score 1):

"Serious" and "grave" would be used to describe the crime itself, rather than the criminal that committed it. A *serious crime* would be one that had a great impact on others and perhaps attracts a severe penalty. I can't recall ever hearing "serious criminal".

If you want to show gradations of how serious the crimes committed are, focus on the crime itself rather than the criminal. You could say:

- He committed serious crimes
- His crimes were of a serious nature

Or use comparative terms:

- He is the worse criminal
- He is the greater criminal

Note that someone who persistently commits crimes (ie a repeat offender) is sometimes called *a career criminal*.

There is also a term for someone who does not commit very serious crimes, and that is *a petty criminal*. "Petty crimes" are defined differently in the law of different countries, but in the UK it would include things like trespassing, minor theft ("petty theft") such as shoplifting. As this term exists, "criminal" in isolation would generally infer that the crimes had a degree of severity.